# RequestDispatcher.include() from custom tags and IllegalStateExceptions

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, character-encoding

In a custom tag, I want to include other things through the RequestDispatcher:

```
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher(url);
rd.include(request, response);
```

but I can not know the state of the response's output stream. I am currently working around this by wrapping the response and the JspWriter available to the tag in another object that implements HttpServletRequest. when there is a call to getWriter() inside, this works fine. But if code handling the request actually wants to get the raw OutputStream (which i cannot safely get within the tag, either), I get an IllegalStateException (because getOutputStream() has already been called).

Now I could ALSO create a new OutputStream and wrap it up in my request wrapper, buffer it until the include() returns, and then get the bytes written into it and write them to the JspWriter.

My question, however, is this: should I try to maintain character encodings? as in: should I "mock" even more of the response object so I can at least try to do a conversion from the character encoding set in the request wrapper I pass into the include and the underlying outputstream? Would this be "clean enough"? Are there any utility classes I should look into?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use both getServletOutputStream() and getWriter() in same response.

I think somewhere in your code you are using getServletOutputStream() and including JSP's uses getWriter(). This is causing you the exception.

Please see the duplicate question.

[java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already using output stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15676337/java-lang-illegalstateexception-already-using-output-stream/15676991#15676991)

Comment: yes, i know. my problem is actually that i don't know which one will be used when i include some other resource.

Comment: and the receiving side cannot know wether or not it is "allowed" to getWriter or getOutputStream ... it has to assume the response is a fresh one and it can do anything it wants with it.