# java.lang.IllegalStateException: getWriter() has already been called for this response2

Tags: java, jsp, jasper-reports, httpserver

In my JasperReports project I have created report and trying to generate it, but continuously getting the below exception:

```
Severe:   java.lang.IllegalStateException: getWriter() has already been called for this response
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getOutputStream(Response.java:746)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getOutputStream(ResponseFacade.java:206)
    at com.vehicletracking.vtss.classes.jsfbean.JasperReportBean.pdf(JasperReportBean.java:35)
    at com.vehicletracking.vtss.classes.jsfbean.DailyTrackingBean.generatePDFReport(DailyTrackingBean.java:471)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:326)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:536)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:136)
```

Here is my code:

```
public class JasperReportBean {

    public String pdf(List<DailyTrakingReportBean> jasperReportList) throws JRException, IOException {
        try {
            JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanCollectionDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(jasperReportList);
            String reportPath = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRealPath("/reports/newReport.jasper");
            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportPath, new HashMap(), beanCollectionDataSource);
            HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
            httpServletResponse.addHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=FleetReport.pdf");
            ServletOutputStream outputStream = httpServletResponse.getOutputStream();
            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, outputStream);
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

And here is my libraries:

[image]

I cannot understand where I am doing mistake.

Comment: See [this answer regarding getOutputStream and get Writer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15676991/5191221).

Comment: I have seen this but i cannot able to replace getOutputStream() with getWriter(). Its give me lots of errors

Comment: I think the question is how to get the correct getWriter which is already in use. If you already tried getWriter, think about updating your question with the error and the things you've tried.

Comment: I am not using getWriter in anywhere in code

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I didn't mean that *you* are using it. It seems that the *Jasper Framework* uses it. Now the question is how to get the corrent writer.

Comment: I resolved this by simple make string method to void

Comment: but problem is now i am getting new server worming:

Comment: log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.ExtensionsEnvironment).

Comment: Please use the edit function to update your question with a complete code sample and stack trace. Comments are not sufficient for this.