# Download PDF file stored in MySQL database in Blob format with jsp

Tags: java, html, sql, jsp

I'm trying to download PDF file stored in MySQL database in Long Blob format.

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="loginHomeLogin" class="col-sm-6">
    <h2>Download file</h2>
    <form method="post"  action="downloadProject?id=${id}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      Download:
        <input type="submit" value="Download" name="Download" id="download" />
    </form>
</div>
```

here the java servelt page (downloadProject) called from the button

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    ResultSet rs = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    Connection db = null;
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);

    OutputStream outx = null;
    InputStream filecontent = null;
    int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096; 
    try {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
        DataSource ds = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/webdb2");
        db = ds.getConnection();

        String id = request.getParameter("id");

        ps = db.prepareStatement("select * from tableName where id=?");
        ps.setInt(1,Integer.parseInt(id));
        rs=ps.executeQuery(); 


        while(rs.next()){

            Blob blob = rs.getBlob("fieldName");  
            InputStream inputStream = blob.getBinaryStream();
            int fileLength = inputStream.available();

            ServletContext context = getServletContext();

            // sets MIME type for the file download
            String mimeType = context.getMimeType(fileName);
            if (mimeType == null) {         
                mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
            }               

            response.setContentType(mimeType);
            response.setContentLength(fileLength);
            String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
            String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", fileName);
            response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);

            // writes the file to the client
            OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            int bytesRead = -1;

            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            inputStream.close();
            outStream.close(); 

        }

        request.getSession(true).setAttribute("ins", "success");;
        response.sendRedirect("home");

    }
```

the error returned is:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getWriter() has already been called for this response, an http error 500 with the page and an empty pdf downloaded.
Where is the error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already using output stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15676337/java-lang-illegalstateexception-already-using-output-stream)

Comment: @uneq95 removing PrintWriter outw = response.getWriter(); the error is: org.apache.coyote.http11.HeadersTooLargeException: An attempt was made to write more data to the response headers than there was room available in the buffer. Increase maxHttpHeaderSize on the connector or write less data into the response headers.